# How can I use Excel to calculate the number of recent, consecutive fiscal years someone has made a gift to my company?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I am working at a nonprofit and we are trying to get a project off the ground where we send people postcards celebrating how many years they have been giving to us.

I am working with Excel in Office 365 on my Windows desktop. My knowledge level of Excel is probably somewhere between Intermediate and Advanced. This is my first post here so I hope I do this correctly.

Here's a small sample of the data I am working with:

| ID | Gift 5 | Gift 4 | Gift 3 | Gift 2 | Gift 1 | Desired Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0063532 | 2/12/2020 | 2/12/2020 | 2/12/2020 | 12/23/2019 | 12/20/2019 | 1 |
| 0038837 | 2/12/2020 | 10/3/2017 | 12/1/2016 | 11/20/2015 | 9/18/2014 | 1 |
| 0971229 | 2/7/2020 | 6/30/2019 | 5/31/2019 | 3/18/2019 | 3/5/2019 | 2 |
| 0113996 | 2/12/2020 | 2/12/2019 | 11/29/2016 | 7/19/2002 |  | 2 |
| 0974727 | 2/20/2020 | 2/20/2020 | 9/23/2019 | 10/2/2018 | 12/13/2017 | 3 |
| 0176357 | 2/12/2020 | 10/16/2018 | 6/13/2018 | 9/14/2015 | 10/29/2014 | 3 |
| 0031280 | 2/12/2020 | 2/4/2019 | 1/23/2018 | 1/25/2017 | 2/29/2016 | 5 |

Their most recent gift must be from within the past 12 months, and the years must be consecutive, so if they gave in FY2020, FY2019, FY2017, FY2016, and FY2015, they have been giving consistently for 2 years, because they skipped FY2018. Like I said, the most recent gift should be from the past 12 months, so if someone gave in FY2016, FY2015, FY2014, FY2013 and FY2012, the solution should return a zero for them because even though they had 5 years of consistent giving, they've since broken their streak.

That's the other caveat to this, we want to base it on fiscal years, not calendar years. Our fiscal year starts July 1 and ends June 30.

Above I've provided some sample data, but of course in actuality we have about 25k constituents, some of whom have been giving for over 35 years, frequently many times a year. The real sheet in question here has many, many columns of gift dates (one for each gift ever recorded). The ID column is a unique Identifier for each donor. The column on the far right is the value I would like the solution to return, its not a value that would actually be present on the sheet to begin with.

---

So far, I tried to implement a solution where I created new columns, one for each fiscal year, and then searched all the gift dates for a gift that that takes place in that fiscal year. If there was such a gift, it would put the date in the column just so there was some sort of flag there. Then I had one final row that started with the left most fiscal year, and started counting and kept counting as long as it encountered cells that contained a value.

Sample formula that searches for a gift in a given fiscal year (I have another sheet with the start and end dates for every fiscal year, thats what's being refenced):

```
=IFNA(IFS(AND(B2<'fiscal year dates'!$B$2,B2>'fiscal year dates'!$A$2),B2,AND(C2<'fiscal year dates'!$B$2,C2>'fiscal year dates'!$A$2),C2,AND(D2<'fiscal year dates'!$B$2,D2>'fiscal year dates'!$A$2),D2,AND(E2<'fiscal year dates'!$B$2,E2>'fiscal year dates'!$A$2),E2,AND(F2<'fiscal year dates'!$B$2,F2>'fiscal year dates'!$A$2),F2),"")
```

Sample formula that counts number of recent consecutive fiscal years:

```
=IF(IFERROR((MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(G2:K2="",0),0)-1),5)=0,"",IFERROR((MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(G2:K2="",0),0)-1),5))
```

Here's how this solution looks in Excel:

| ID | Gift 5 | Gift 4 | Gift 3 | Gift 2 | Gift 1 | FY20 | FY19 | FY18 | FY17 | FY16 | Continuous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0063532 | 2/12/2020 | 2/12/2020 | 2/12/2020 | 12/23/2019 | 12/20/2019 | 2/12/2020 |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| 0038837 | 2/12/2020 | 10/3/2017 | 12/1/2016 | 11/20/2015 | 9/18/2014 | 2/12/2020 |  | 10/3/2017 | 12/1/2016 | 11/20/2015 | 1 |
| 0971229 | 2/7/2020 | 6/30/2019 | 5/31/2019 | 3/18/2019 | 3/5/2019 | 2/7/2020 | 5/31/2019 |  |  |  | 2 |
| 0113996 | 2/12/2020 | 2/12/2019 | 11/29/2016 | 7/19/2002 |  | 2/12/2020 | 2/12/2019 |  | 11/29/2016 |  | 2 |
| 0974727 | 2/20/2020 | 2/20/2020 | 9/23/2019 | 10/2/2018 | 12/13/2017 | 2/20/2020 | 10/2/2018 | 12/13/2017 |  |  | 3 |
| 0176357 | 2/12/2020 | 10/16/2018 | 6/13/2018 | 9/14/2015 | 10/29/2014 | 2/12/2020 | 10/16/2018 | 6/13/2018 |  | 9/14/2015 | 3 |
| 0031280 | 2/12/2020 | 2/4/2019 | 1/23/2018 | 1/25/2017 | 2/29/2016 | 2/12/2020 | 2/4/2019 | 1/23/2018 | 1/25/2017 | 2/29/2016 | 5 |

This solution works, I just worry about implementing it on my full data set, when I will have 35 fiscal year columns and hundreds of Gift Date columns. I also worry about duplicating the process month after month. Doing it once might be manageable, but applying it to this report each month to check for anniversaries would be pretty unreasonable.

I feel like this should be something excel is capable of, but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around how to do it efficiently. Please let me know your thoughts! I am open to any type of solution for this. Its been driving me crazy for months now.

Comment: I would llike to warn you against using Excel (or any spreadsheet) as a database.  Plenty of database servers around - some of the best are even free.

Comment: We have a database, thank you for pointing this out though. The excel contains the results from a report that we ran on our database. I'm sure there is probably a way to write a query that would get us this information straight out of the relational database we use, but I can't even begin to figure out how to do that.

Comment: That same report could give you the answer immediately, if someone were to add a little logic to it.

Comment: I'm 100% sure you're right, but no one employed at my organization is able to do that. I guess I did ask for "any type of solution" so technically your comment is fair, but its not a viable solution at this point. 

On an unrelated note: I posted the solution I received via Reddit, which I now see someone downvoted—which is fine, but I just wanted to post it here in case anyone ever ran across a similar question and found this post. I didn't think I should repost the answer itself here, because I wanted to give credit to the person who solved it for me.

Comment: Not my downvote, but StackExchange loves to leach.  I mean: they want you to copy the solution and present it here.  "what if the original site goes down" etc.  Some of them are less likely to go down than SE itself.  BTW, I hope you do have support for your DB, in case of upgrades or changes to the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this on Reddit, and someone there was able to answer my question. Here's a link to the answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/l74rsa/calculating_consecutive_fiscal_years_giving/